# How to save the mutikey array values in mongodb using nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Im using this schema for mulikey array

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var ConfigSchema = new Schema({
    aaaa  : String,

    bbbb  : String,



    Stage: [{
        cccc : String,
        dddd : String,
        eeee : String,

    }, {index: true}]

}, { collection: 'Config' });

var ConfigModel = mongoose.model('Config', ConfigSchema);
module.exports = ConfigModel;
```

and im getting values of stages from html pages correctly. But while assigning values , there is some error that it stores only the last stage.(i.e , it is overwriting values each time the for loop runs)
here the code for assiging values,

```
 var i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i <= 1; i++) {
        var addConfigModel = new ConfigModel(


            {

                aaaa : objmodel.aaa.value,

                bbbb : objmodel.bbb.value,


                Stage: [{
                      cccc : objmodel.Stage[i].ccc.value,
                      dddd : objmodel.Stage[i].ddd.value,
                      eeee : objmodel.Stage[i].eee.value,
                   }]

            });

    }
```

values of cccc ,dddd and eeee stored in mongodb are only last array number values.
Is something wrong in my schema? how to store the values of each stage in mongo?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure you are using the mongodb properly

- When you create a new document in the database you use `new ConfigModel()`
- When you are trying to update an existing document you use `find my doc.update()`

So you are recreating each time your `ConfigModule` document with default values and adding in the array the last value.

So I suggest you to optimise a little bit your code in something like:

```
var config = new ConfigModel()
config.aaaa = objmodel.aaa.value
config.bbbb = objmodel.bbb.value
config.Stage = [0, 1].map((i) => {
 return {
   cccc : objmodel.Stage[i].ccc.value,
   dddd : objmodel.Stage[i].ddd.value,
   eeee : objmodel.Stage[i].eee.value,
 }
})
config.save(() => {
 //
})
```

And this will do the trick

Comment: This also seems good. I got the result by storing the 'stage'  as  a array, previuosly it was in object. And assigning it directly without child elements . i.e , aaaa : objmodel.aaa.value,
                        bbbb : objmodel.bbb.value,
                        Stage: objmodel.Stage. Thanks. I wil try this also.

Comment: Glad It helped nive